# Adding text to a header using check boxes within a word document

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, header, ms-word

I need to create a word template that adds text linked to a check box to a header on every page of the document.

I need 4 check boxes in the document that will add different text to a header when they're clicked upon, I have already completed this function to add text to a body page of the document but cannot figure out for the life of me how I can get it in the header.

Also if this requires the use of visual studio, can my template be exported as a singular file? Or do I always require the project folder to open my template containing additional code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following page. Maybe it will help you.

How to: Add Headers and Footers to Documents http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178795(v=vs.100).aspx